# Making a Slash Command appear in Discord UI

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

On discord, the module `discord.ext.commands` lets you create commands. I tried to create a command, with prefix="/", although it won't appear in discord's UI.

Code:

```html
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

@bot.command(name="kick", description="Kick a user to your wish.")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"The user @{member} has been kicked. Reason: {reason}.")

bot.run("mytoken")
```

It won't pop up.
[image: no pop-up]

But I want to do it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `discord-py-slash-command` version 1.1.2 and then put the code to import it `from discord-py-slash-command import SlashCommands`. You can refer the code below:

```
import discord
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True) # Declares slash commands through the client.

guild_ids = [1234567890] # Put your server IDs in this array.

@slash.slash(name="ping", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def _ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

client.run("token")
```